# What is the native way to import more than one module into a web page?

Tags: javascript, module

ES2015 module loading is now supported natively. I want to avoid transpilation, and as I understand it, modules cannot be natively bundled into a single file without transpilation.

What is the native way to import more than one module into a web page? Is it lots of `<script type=“module” src=“...”>` imports?

Or can I import all my modules into one module and then re-export them from that single module, and then have only a single `script` tag in my HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or can I import all my modules into one module and then re-export them from that single module, and then have only a single script tag in my HTML?

This can work, though usually the setup would be different. Each module can have its own dependencies, so rather than a single hub from which all other modules are imported from, I'd often expect a single **entry point** from which other modules get imported, and the process continues recursively, eventually resulting in a tree-like structure, and not a dandelion.

If you have multiple *entirely separate* scripts (for example, one which renders a chart on the page, and another which adds JS functionality to the *rest* of the page), that'd be a situation where it could sense to have separate initial `<script>` tags for each, if you wanted.

Comment: I’m trying to understand how to get a big tree of modules loaded into the browser, without transpilation. I can import a single `entry-point.js` into the browser via a script tag (type module). If that entry point imports and re-exports all the top-level modules in my app, will the browser automatically download the entire module tree?

Comment: Yes, it will. (That's one of the reasons I'm not entirely sold on native modules, because in reasonable sized projects with large numbers of small, maintainable script files, that's a *lot* of different connections that need to be made)

Comment: HTTP2 appears to try to mitigate this via multiplexing over a single HTTP connection.